# Redirect issues: non www to www

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, multisite

I have a WordPress Multisite setup.

I'm trying to redirect non-www to www.

However, I get the following (see screenshot):

[image: Screenshot]

Below is my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lpnevada.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.lpnevada.org/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: It would really make more sense if you let us see what exactly is going on, instead of blurrying stuff in the screenshot, when we can read the domain `lpnevada.org` in the code you have shown anyway …

Comment: Such redirects should always happen _before_ any internal rewrites. And the comments `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` mark the part of the .htaccess you are _not_ supposed to modify anything in in the first place - because WordPress will _replace_ anything in there, when you flush your permalink settings.

Comment: @CBroe So do I put the last 2 lines of that module (to rewrite non-www to www) before #Begin Wordpress ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the settings within WordPress itself instead of in the .htaccess file. Change the "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)" under Settings > General to: https://www.example.com

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```